# how to check if Azure Function is still running or not

Tags: function, azure

I have a situation where i have to call an Azure function periodically.
When i call the function, i need to check the state of the azure function.
If the Azure function is running, then i need to postpone the call until it is completed.

I am trying to look in an Email Queue (as the emails are coming in), I need to send the email using Amazon SES

I am using a HTTPtrigger and the email part is working fine.

I don't want the function to be called, when it is already running.

Comment: That's not how Azure Functions work. Each request gets its own Function instance. You don't have to wait. AWS Lambdas work the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the serverless architecture, each time whenever you invoke a service endpoint, a new instance will be created and scaling is managed by scaling controller.

There is no way to check if the function is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding more about your use-case, I think this is possible with Durable Functions. Look up [Eternal Orchestrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations?tabs=csharp) that call themselves on an interval indefinitely. You can then query the status if required and have a workflow in the eternal orchestration that changes depending on certain criteria.